# How to use Solver Handler in MRTK and Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I'm looking to have a object following the controller position with the MRTK in unity, I added an gameobject to the scene and added a Solver Handler to it with `Hand Joint` as `target type`, `Right` as `handness` and `Palm` as `Hand joint` but it does nothing.
I see the controller moving and the game object not moving at all.
I don't find any explanation nor tutorial to how make it work.

Comment: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html -> The `SolverHandler` alone does nothing yet .. you also need `Solver` component/s which consume/s it

Comment: Can you remove the -1 ? The doc isn't clear it's written "In order to use the Solver system, simply add one of the components listed above to a GameObject."

Comment: I didn't downvote but vote to close as this question is offtopic due to asking for a tutorial or external reference

Comment: Sorry maybe it's unclear because I'm not a native english speaker, but really it's unclear to me. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application designed to be manipulated directly with hands? Articulated hand tracking system is a new capability of HoloLens2. If you are using HoloLens1 or Immersive headsets, you will not be able to use the hand joint.

And I noticed the "**controller**" mentioned in your question, I think you may be using the Motion controller to interact with your application. If so, you should change the `Tracked Target Type` as `Controller Ray`. More information please see: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html#how-to-change-tracking-reference